# Duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 FireBase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have those pod installed:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

target 'xxx' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'RSKImageCropper'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
  pod 'Base64', '~> 1.1.2'
  pod 'BGTableViewRowActionWithImage'
  pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
  pod 'TYMProgressBarView'
  pod 'MobileVLCKit'
end
```

And when i install this pod : `pod 'Firebase/Crash' my project can't build and i have this error: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffzjv.png)

Comment: It looks like you have duplicate symbols with the following libraries:                  Firebase <-> Google Maps. Firebase is owned by Google so I guess thats why they use the same symbols of some classes that already exist in GoogleMaps. I'd try updating both of those frameworks/pods, and hopefully newer versions fixed it.

Comment: If there is no update to both, I'd suggest following this tutorial in order to avoid duplicate symbols: http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries It will allow you to create one big library from the two libraries, without the duplicate symbols.